# SQLite data in a Custom ListView inside a Fragment

Tags: android

I have created half of my app and I am stuck where I need to retrieve the data from the SQLite database and show them in a ListView inside a Tab Fragment.

I have two tabs and one of them will show the list of data from SQLite database.
Some people on stackoverflow recommended some tutorial, link and video but it is difficult for me to use a ListView in a fragment.

I am new to Android and I think these problems are not that hard for professional developers, but for me it is quite difficult.

It is a project to make for the school and I am totally stuck, please help me
This is my code

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "ussd.db";

public static final String TABLE_OFFRE = "offre_table";
public static final String TABLE_ADMIN = "admin_table";

public static final String COL_1 = "ID";
public static final String COL_2 = "CODE";
public static final String COL_3 = "NAME";
public static final String COL_4 = "USSD";

public static final String COL_A1 = "ID";
public static final String COL_A2 = "NOM";
public static final String COL_A3 = "NUMERO";


public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(" create table " + TABLE_OFFRE + "(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,CODE TEXT UNIQUE,NAME TEXT,USSD TEXT);");
    db.execSQL(" create table " + TABLE_ADMIN + "(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,NOM TEXT,NUMERO TEXT UNIQUE);");
}
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + TABLE_OFFRE+";");
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + TABLE_ADMIN+";");
    onCreate(db);
}
public boolean insertData(String code, String name, String ussd){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL_2,code);
    contentValues.put(COL_3,name);
    contentValues.put(COL_4,ussd);
    long result = db.insert(TABLE_OFFRE,null,contentValues);
    if (result == -1){
        return false;
    }else {
        return true;
    }
}
public boolean insertAdmin(String nom, String numero){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL_A2,nom);
    contentValues.put(COL_A3,numero);
    long result = db.insert(TABLE_ADMIN,null,contentValues);
    if (result == -1){
        return false;
    }else {
        return true;
    }
}
public Cursor getAllData(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from " + TABLE_OFFRE,null);
    return res;
}
public Cursor getAllAdmin(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from " + TABLE_ADMIN,null);
    return res;
}
```

}

and my listview

```
public class listadmin extends Fragment {
DatabaseHelper myDb;
private ListView listView;
private listadmin MyListAdapter;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listadmin, container, false);
    ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.ListViewadmin);
    return rootView;
}
```

}

Comment: Shouldn't you just use a `CursorAdapter`?

Comment: I do not know how to use CursorAdapter with a fragment

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15077669/android-populating-a-listview-using-fragments-and-a-simple-cursor-adapter